# match with two optional lookaheads

Tags: regex

Let there be two strings that can appear at the end of a paragraph.  The paragraph may not have any of the endings, have only one ending or have both endings in any order.  My task is to capture the paragraph proceeding any possible endings combination.

For this example, suppose:

- the first ending is “I’m so glad to be home again!” and
- the second ending is "After all, tomorrow is another day."

Some Examples:

- String: "This is well-told story. After all, tomorrow is another day."
- Match: "This is well-told story."

or

- String: "A story with no end."
- Match: "A story with no end."

or

- string: "A children's story. I’m so glad to be home again! After all, tomorrow is another day."
- Match: "A children's story."

or

- string: "Another sentence in a Romance novel. I’m so glad to be home again!
- Match: "Another sentence in a Romance novel"

I tried:

```
.*(?=“I’m so glad to be home again)(?=After all, tomorrow is another day)
```

but it doesn't work for all scenarios.

Comment: Try: `^(contents\.).*`

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear.  "contents" can be any string and I don't know it ahead of time.  regardless of the string input, I need to crop any combination of first ending or second ending where I know the endings regex pattern

Comment: @Eric are you trying to match just `contents.` in each example, or are you also trying to match your unique endings? Are you trying to match all 5 examples you gave, or just 2-5, or just 4&5? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Reread your question and throw out all preconceived knowledge you have about your problem and then reword + add details to your question. We're having to fill gaps and make assumptions because you haven't given us enough information

Comment: I've obviously botched this question somehow.  thanks for trying to help.  I rephrased it with another example and I hope its clearer - at least I tried!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(contents. )((first ending)|(second ending))*
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/lb098N/1

Comment: again, it fails in the general case I'm describing.  I need to capture an unknown string followed by known optional endings